# Why are my MySQL connections running slower on localhost than through network?

Tags: mysql

This is my basic scenario: I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 web application which connects to a MySQL database through MySQL .net connector 6.5.4 . I have this scenario for almost a year, but some weeks ago we had to move all the data to another hard drive (not sure if that is the problem, but ...), so I dumped the database, installed everything on this new HD and deployed my system. The problem I'm having is that it got really slow to access a specific page after all this modifications. When I say really slow I mean 30 minutes load time. The problem is: on my machine, pointing to this same database, I don't have this big delay ... and they're both running the same version of the system.

Do you guys have any ideas on how to solve this or where to look first?

Answer (score 1):

I would say the first candidate would be reverse DNS lookups, and if you don't need DNS lookups, try to use [`--skip-name-resolve`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-name-resolve).